# indicate function arguments in math

Tags: math-mode

I want to write a function but not repeat its arguments, but I don't like the font options I see. For example $A(\cdot)$ or $A(\bullet)$ aren't pleasant.

Any recommended alternatives?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SW. This is very opinion based question and such it has  very little common with LaTeX. So it is off-tošic here.

Comment: I tend to use `\mrkarg` defined as `{}\cdot{}` because `\cdot)` is often too hard to see. In any case it is best to have a macro for it, then you can always replace the symbols if needed.